# Javascript / Validation for input

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

I need to create a new student in a DOT NET MVC View page.

Form and input in a View that uses `Student` class as its Model :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new {onsubmit = "return Validation();"}
   <input type="text" name="Student.Name">
```

Validation.js:

```
var form = document.forms[0];
var studetnName = form["Student.Name"].value;

if(!studentName) // if user didn't input anything
{
    form[Student.Name].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    form[Student.Name].innerHtml = "This field is required!"
    return false;
}

return true;
```

If I use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class="form-control" })` helper instead of regular HTML input (given in first example). How do I refer to this field in my Validation.js file?
Do i just add attribute `new { name = "testName" }` to my HTML helper and refer to it in .js file as

`var studetnName = form["testName"].value` or what is the solution here?

Answer (score 0):

**javascript code**

```
function validateForm() {
      var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
      if (x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
      }
    }
```

**html code for textbox**

```
<form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```